# Why am I seeing two canvases when using PIXI.js in my Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, pixi.js

I'm developing a game using PIXI.js in a Next.js application. However, I'm encountering an issue where two canvases are being rendered on the page instead of a single canvas. This behavior is causing unexpected rendering and functionality problems. I've checked my code and made sure there are no duplicate calls to create canvases or add them to the DOM.

index.js:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import { Howl } from 'howler';
import { createCharacter, handleCharacterClick } from '../utils/character.js';
import { createScoreCounter, incrementScore, getScore, getScoreCounter } from '../utils/score.js';
import { createBonusCounter, incrementBonusScore, decayBonusScore } from '../utils/bonus.js';

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let app;

    function resize() {
      const aspectRatio = 719 / 420; // Aspect ratio of the background image

      let w, h;

      if (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight > aspectRatio) {
        w = window.innerHeight * aspectRatio;
        h = window.innerHeight;
      } else {
        w = window.innerWidth;
        h = window.innerWidth / aspectRatio;
      }

      app.view.style.width = w + 'px';
      app.view.style.height = h + 'px';
      app.view.style.left = (window.innerWidth - w) / 2 + 'px'; // Center horizontally
      app.view.style.top = (window.innerHeight - h) / 2 + 'px'; // Center vertically
    }

    // Load the background image and get its dimensions
    let backgroundImageOnLoad = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
      img.onerror = reject;
      img.src = '/assets/images/bed.jpg';
    });

    backgroundImageOnLoad.then(dimensions => {
      // create a new Pixi application with the same dimensions as the background image
      app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: dimensions.width,
        height: dimensions.height
      });

      // call resize function to properly size the view initially
      resize();

      // add the app view (canvas element) to the document body
      document.getElementById('game').appendChild(app.view);

      // create a texture from the background image and add it to the stage
      let backgroundTexture = PIXI.Texture.from('/assets/images/bed.jpg');
      let backgroundSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(backgroundTexture);
      app.stage.addChild(backgroundSprite);

      // create character and add to stage
      let character = createCharacter(app);
      character.interactive = true;
      character.on('pointerdown', () => {
        handleCharacterClick(character, app);
        incrementScore();
      });
      app.stage.addChild(character);

      // create and add score counter to stage
      createScoreCounter();
      let scoreCounter = getScoreCounter();
      app.stage.addChild(scoreCounter);

      // create and add bonus counter to stage
      const bonusCounter = createBonusCounter();
      app.stage.addChild(bonusCounter.container);

      // Load the background music
      const backgroundMusic = new Howl({
        src: ['/assets/audio/background-music-2.mp3'],
        loop: true,
        volume: 0.5,
      });

      // Play the background music
      backgroundMusic.play();

      // attach resize function to window resize event
      window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    });

    // cleanup logic if needed
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="game"></div>
  );
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <meta name="next-head-count" content="2">
      <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
      <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1688999013977"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1688999013977" defer=""></script>
      <style>
         /*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IiIsInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ== */
      </style>
      <noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="__next">
         <div id="game">
            <canvas style="touch-action: none; width: 883.343px; height: 516px; left: 518.329px; top: 0px; cursor: inherit;" width="719" height="420"></canvas>
            <canvas style="touch-action: none; width: 883.343px; height: 516px; left: 518.329px; top: 0px; cursor: inherit;" width="719" height="420"></canvas>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1688999013977"></script><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{}},"page":"/","query":{},"buildId":"development","nextExport":true,"autoExport":true,"isFallback":false,"scriptLoader":[]}</script>
      <div id="__next-build-watcher" style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; right: 20px; width: 0px; height: 0px; z-index: 99999;" data-dashlane-shadowhost="true" data-dashlane-observed="true"></div>
      <next-route-announcer>
         <p aria-live="assertive" id="__next-route-announcer__" role="alert" style="border: 0px none; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-wrap: normal;"></p>
      </next-route-announcer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import { Howl } from 'howler';
import { createCharacter, handleCharacterClick } from '../utils/character.js';
import { createScoreCounter, incrementScore, getScore, getScoreCounter } from '../utils/score.js';
import { createBonusCounter, incrementBonusScore, decayBonusScore } from '../utils/bonus.js';

export default function Home() {
  const gameRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let app;

    function resize() {
      const aspectRatio = 719 / 420; // Aspect ratio of the background image

      let w, h;

      if (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight > aspectRatio) {
        w = window.innerHeight * aspectRatio;
        h = window.innerHeight;
      } else {
        w = window.innerWidth;
        h = window.innerWidth / aspectRatio;
      }

      if (app) {
        app.renderer.resize(w, h);
      }
    }

    // Load the background image and get its dimensions
    let backgroundImageOnLoad = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
      img.onerror = reject;
      img.src = '/assets/images/bed.jpg';
    });

    backgroundImageOnLoad.then(dimensions => {
      // create a new Pixi application with the same dimensions as the background image
      app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: dimensions.width,
        height: dimensions.height,
        view: gameRef.current,
      });

      // call resize function to properly size the view initially
      resize();

      // create a texture from the background image and add it to the stage
      let backgroundTexture = PIXI.Texture.from('/assets/images/bed.jpg');
      let backgroundSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(backgroundTexture);
      app.stage.addChild(backgroundSprite);

      // create character and add to stage
      let character = createCharacter(app);
      character.interactive = true;
      character.on('pointerdown', () => {
        handleCharacterClick(character, app);
        incrementScore();
      });
      app.stage.addChild(character);

      // create and add score counter to stage
      createScoreCounter();
      let scoreCounter = getScoreCounter();
      app.stage.addChild(scoreCounter);

      // create and add bonus counter to stage
      const bonusCounter = createBonusCounter();
      app.stage.addChild(bonusCounter.container);

      // Load the background music
      const backgroundMusic = new Howl({
        src: ['/assets/audio/background-music-2.mp3'],
        loop: true,
        volume: 0.5,
      });

      // Play the background music
      backgroundMusic.play();

      // attach resize function to window resize event
      window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    });

    // cleanup logic if needed
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
      app?.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas id="game" ref={gameRef}></canvas>;
}
```

The double rendering of the canvas was caused by the original code appending the PIXI application's view (canvas element) to the document body in the useEffect hook. This resulted in two canvas elements being rendered, one from the JSX in the return statement () and the other created by PIXI (app.view).

In the updated code, we use a useRef hook to create a reference to a single canvas element (gameRef). By assigning this canvas element as the view option when creating the PIXI application (app = new PIXI.Application({ view: gameRef.current })), we ensure that PIXI renders its content onto the specific canvas referenced by gameRef.

This approach avoids the double rendering issue because we are now directly controlling the rendering target of PIXI, rather than appending its view to the document body. Only a single canvas element is created and rendered by PIXI, eliminating the duplication.